# Strugging to simplify HashMap object placement

Tags: java, android, json, list, hashmap

I am creating a SimpleExpandableListAdapter and having trouble placing object into there respective groups without having a lot of code.

The layout is:
[Monday]
- childGroup1 data
[Tuesday]
- childGroup2 data

I have a JSON array which returns a list of lessons for a user, and these need to be sorted by day, and placed into there respective expandable header however my code is very long, I was wondering if there is any simpler way to do this that I may have overlooked?

I am getting the JSON object, checking the day it is on and storing the data for that lesson into the days group.

I feel that the way I have coded this is too long, and looking for ways to improve this code thanks to make it more dynamic.

```
//child data
List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> childData = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String, String>>>();
List<HashMap<String,String>> childGroup0 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
List<HashMap<String,String>> childGroup1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
List<HashMap<String,String>> childGroup2 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
List<HashMap<String,String>> childGroup3 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
List<HashMap<String,String>> childGroup4 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
List<HashMap<String,String>> childGroup5 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
List<HashMap<String,String>> childGroup6 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hm.put("moduleName", jObj.getString("moduleName"));
    hm.put("startTime",
            (jObj.getString("startTime")).substring(0, 5));
    hm.put("endTime",
            (jObj.getString("endTime")).substring(0, 5));
    hm.put("group", jObj.getString("group"));
    hm.put("roomName", jObj.getString("roomName"));
    hm.put("firstName", jObj.getString("firstName"));
    hm.put("lastName", jObj.getString("lastName"));

    switch (Integer.parseInt(jObj.getString("day"))){
    case 0:
        childGroup0.add(hm);
        break;
    case 1:
        childGroup1.add(hm);
        break;
    case 2:
        childGroup2.add(hm);
        break;
    case 3:
        childGroup3.add(hm);
        break;
    case 4:
        childGroup4.add(hm);
        break;
    case 5:
        childGroup5.add(hm);
        break;
    case 6:
        childGroup6.add(hm);
        break;
    }                            
}
childData.add(childGroup0);
childData.add(childGroup1);
childData.add(childGroup2);
childData.add(childGroup3);
childData.add(childGroup4);
childData.add(childGroup5);
childData.add(childGroup6);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, get rid of all those `childGroup` objects and just add them into your `childData` as an list item. Also this will cause an error if `jObj.getString("day") > 6` so maybe you want to add some logic in there to say if it is > 6 then add it to a different group.

```
List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> childData = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String, String>>>();
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    childData.add(new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>());
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) { 
    JSONObject jObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);  

    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hm.put("moduleName", jObj.getString("moduleName"));
    hm.put("startTime",
            (jObj.getString("startTime")).substring(0, 5));
    hm.put("endTime",
            (jObj.getString("endTime")).substring(0, 5));
    hm.put("group", jObj.getString("group"));
    hm.put("roomName", jObj.getString("roomName"));
    hm.put("firstName", jObj.getString("firstName"));
    hm.put("lastName", jObj.getString("lastName"));

    childData.get(Integer.parseInt(jObj.getString("day"))).add(hm);
}
```

Comment: +1. Also, as a brevity thing _plus_ "proper" use of polymorphism, you should probably change the `HashMap` generic param to just `Map`: `childData = new ArrayList<List<Map<String, String>>>()` (and in other places where you have a `List<HashMap<...>>`).